# Adding image on top of a view using Xcode4.2, assistance needed

Tags: uiview, storyboard, xcode4.2

In my `UIViewController` file, inside `viewDidLoad` method, i

```
CGRect gameArea = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100);

UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cards.png"]; 
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];

UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:gameArea];
[topView addSubview:myImageView];    

[[self view] addSubview:topView];
```

My expectation is that on top of existing view, a rectangle will show up with the image as his background.

**Instead app crashes. What am i doing wrong?**

It does not seem to matter where this code is pasted. I tried putting it as part of `init` - same thing happens. App crashes

**The problem seems to happen here:**

[image]

**The stack trace looks as follows:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my code runs as part of `viewDidLoad` method. By this time, things are established already.

Instead the same code works fine as part of the

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Hope this helps someone